# preg_match expression including white space

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, whitespace

So I'm trying to parse a sequence of numbers that is extracted from an external web page.

```
preg_match('#([0-9]{3}\s[0-9]{3}\s[0-9]{3}){1}#', $element, $match);
```

won't return any result although echoing $element shows the correct expression:

```
341 102 408 AAA Bccc
```

Of course when I try the above regexp with above string on online regexp testers I got the expected result...
I'm thinking that there may be an invisible caracter in place of a white space but can't find it. I'm getting really crazy...

**EDIT:**

Strangely this does remove every whitespace of the input string EXCEPT for the expression I'm trying to extract:

```
$element = preg_replace("/\s/", "", $element);
```

Comment: Do a `var_dump` on input string.

Comment: you know `preg_match` doesn't return the results? in your example `$match` will be an array containing the matches

Comment: Otherwise you could remove the {1} from the end. It is the default.

Comment: Tried var_dump, I still get white spaces, also tried removing {1} with no change

Comment: I'm aware that preg_match won't return results :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
preg_match('#([0-9]{3}\s+[0-9]{3}\s+[0-9]{3}){1}#u', $element, $match);
```

to make the regex engine Unicode-aware, and to allow more than one whitespace character between digits; perhaps you have some non-ASCII whitespace in there.

That said, you can reduce this to

```
preg_match('#(?:[0-9]{3}\s+){2}[0-9]{3}#u', $element, $match);
```

and you will find the match result in `$match[0]` if it succeeded.

Comment: That did the job. Thanks a lot pal!